# Why setTimeout function seems that it does not work into a infinite loop?

Tags: jquery

setTimeout function seems that it does not work into a infinite loop: 
Here the following I have used a setTimeout function but it returns value without any desired delay.

Here the source:

```
var Slider = new function () {
    var that = this;
    for (var i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
        var a = myFunction(i);
        alert(a);
        if (i == 5) {
            i = 0;
        }
    }
};
 function myFunction(n) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        return n;
    }, 3000);
};
```

Comment: Seems like you have an infinite loop to start with. Then how can you possible do any debugging by using `alert()`?

Comment: `myFunction()` will always return immediately, with no return value. Later, the inner function will return `n`, but that value will be ignored, and has nothing to do with any of the code in `Slider`

Comment: `myFunction` does not return any value. `a` value is undefined. I dont clearly understand what you want to do

Comment: Q. The answer you have accepted below does not even run, let alone work. What was your reasoning for accepting it?

Comment: Now I understand why you accepted such a poor answer. You both work for the same company! I see now *yours* is the third serial-upvoting account I have been looking for (combined with Kamruzzaman and Rezoyanul Islam Reza). I think an email to IQRASYS is definitely called for now. This is totally unprofessional behaviour.

Comment: Ok, I got your point but for a long time I use stackoverflow for searching and did not aware of it. But you told I get  series upvotted and do upvotted, it is not completely true, but thanks for warning me.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

it working corrcetly if (-) is one secont then the output return from the function myFunction

```
    --- output
    --- output
    --- output
    --- output
    --- output

var Slider = new function () {
    var that = this;
    for (var i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
        var a = myFunction(i);

        if (i == 5) {
            i = 0;
        }
    }
};
function myFunction(n) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        alert(n);
    }, 3000);
};
```

if you use this code, then you can clear

```
    --- output
    ------ output
    --------- output
    ------------ output
    --------------- output

    var Slider = new function () {
    var that = this;
    for (var i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
        var a = myFunction(i);

        //if (i == 5) {
        //    i = 0;
        //}
    }
};
function myFunction(n) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        alert(n);
    }, (n*3000));
};
```

I stop infinite loop, it also work for infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your `return n` call is returning the value to the `setTimeout` callback. `myFunction` isn't returning anything. So the value you've got in `a` can be anything.

Second, `setTimeout` executes a piece of code after the given timeout, but doesn't block your current execution. This means that your `alert(a)` will be called immediately after you call to `myFunction`, and then, after 3 seconds, the `setTimeout` callback will be executed.